# Create Shape drawable with stroke color, corner and solid drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I Want to create a shape: solid is a Bitmap (repeat tiles), and stroke is a color. I use LayerList:

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/additional_image"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg_detail_loop"
        >
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/rounded_corners"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_box_dlg">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

File bg_detail_loop.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:filter="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:src="@drawable/tile_detail"
    />
```

File shape_box_dlg.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#EE6A1F" />
    <gradient android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

But, in the corner, the background Bitmap not clip. I want rounded the corner. Anyone help me? Thanks